# Python-VLC update next playing track after shuffle

Tags: python, python-3.x, libvlc

I'm writing my own mediaplayer using Python-VLC bindings.

But my shuffle function produces an odd behavior. Whenever I shuffle the medialist while playing a track, the next track will be chosen from the previous unshuffled list, but the track after that using the new shuffled list.

Is there some way to tell it it shall take the next from new list?

code:

```
# Create a basic vlc instance
self.instance = vlc.Instance()
# Create an empty vlc media player
self.mediaplayer = self.instance.media_player_new()
self.medialistplayer = self.instance.media_list_player_new()
self.medialistplayer.set_media_player(self.mediaplayer)
self.medialist = self.instance.media_list_new()
self.medialistplayer.set_media_list(self.medialist)

def shuffle(self):
    self.medialist.lock()
    l = list()
    while len(self.medialist) != 0:
        l.append(self.medialist[0])
        self.medialist.remove_index(0)
    random.shuffle(l)
    for i in l:
        self.medialist.add_media(i)
    self.medialist.unlock()
    self.updateQueue()

def play_pause(self):
    """Toggle play/pause status
    """
    if self.mediaplayer.is_playing():
        self.medialistplayer.pause()
    else:
        self.medialistplayer.play()

def open_file(self,filename=None):
    """Open a media file in a MediaPlayer
    """

    dialog_txt = "Choose Media File"
    if not filename:
        filename = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, dialog_txt, os.path.expanduser('~'))
    else:
        filename = [filename]
    if not filename:
        return
    if filename == ("",""):
        return

    # getOpenFileName returns a tuple, so use only the actual file name
    self.media = self.instance.media_new(filename[0])

    # Put the media in the media player
    self.medialist.add_media(self.media)

    # Parse the metadata of the file
    self.media.parse()

    # Set the title of the track as window title
    self.setWindowTitle(self.media.get_meta(0))

    # The media player has to be 'connected' to the QFrame (otherwise the
    # video would be displayed in it's own window). This is platform
    # specific, so we must give the ID of the QFrame (or similar object) to
    # vlc. Different platforms have different functions for this

    self.updateQueue()
```

Comment: Without the code that shows how playback is controlled or how the queue is handled, it is impossible to say. If you control the queue processing manually, you may have more luck.

Comment: There are `medialist.new` and `release` functions that might bare investigating.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I hope I added everything to my question what helps... I don't really handle the queue myself at all... this are all standard vlc functions...

Comment: I was wondering what was in `self.updateQueue`. Without coding it, I'd try stopping the  player, release the current medialist, create a new one and then set_media_list on the player. Currently, you are shuffling it "in place", which, clearly, is only working partially.

Comment: self.updateQueue is just updating a QTableView

Comment: A `QTableView`? Well that clears things up! Good luck!